# Accessing Files in Other Users FTP Folder?

Tags: permissions, directory, ftp

I have a wifi security camera that writes to an FTP server located on a 16.04 LTS system.  I create the user in Ubuntu and that automatically creates a home folder.  When I create the user in the ftp server, it assigns a folder in the home folder for accepting the video files automatically triggered by the cameras motion sensing.  All that works.

However, in order to see and/ or delete the video files I need to be logged on under the camera's user name.  I would like view and delete access when logged in under my primary name.  I tried running chmod 777 * from the folder holding the files but that killed everyone’s access to the folder, including the camera.  I could not correct so deleted the user in Ubuntu and recreated so I'm now back at the same state in the paragraph above.

Any suggestions on this?  I also want to create an auto run type script to delete files after X days so am concerned how the user rights will affect that.

Answer (score 0):

I had no responses so I'm wondering if this is a dead forum.  Is there a better place to post questions?

I did find something that worked by using groups.  see the link

[how to give read, write and modify access to folders and files in my home directory mutually to other users on same computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471814/how-to-give-read-write-and-modify-access-to-folders-and-files-in-my-home-direct)